# Text mining and Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, text-mining, named-entity-recognition

I have a DataSet of words and texts and I want to make clusters (by K-means )or any other unsupervised/supervised learning method to distinguish words for example , the word 'John' will be classified as a name(and will be clustered with other person names) , 'brazil' as a place and etc...
Is there a model that I can use to solve the problem.
I have Heard of N-grams but I dont know how to plot the Ngrams probability on a x,y plot or such
P.S if you have any examples that will be wonderful

Comment: If you only care about "name" and "place", you should look for named entity solutions. Otherwise, you might want to find/develop a good source of labeled data (with labels you care about) and learn classifier based on that.

Comment: You are describing a *supervised* task, classification.

Comment: I want to cluster the data and then make decisions boundaries so I'll could approximate the word type ( the clusters will be labeled to classes eventually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about word2vec and embeddings?
https://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec

Comment: If you don't have predefined classes word2vec is a good solution. Here you are the solution in tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/word2vec/index.html You can represent the word in the form of a vector and then using for example cosine distance you can do clustering. If you have predefined classes then you must use supervised learning.